# Is it safe to use any arbitrary charger for a smartphone?

Tags: safety, cellphone

Today, most smartphones have USB-C chargers, and this allows to use any charger with any phone. The issue I have, though, is that these chargers have different amperage, different wattage and so on. For instance, I attach the picture of a charger I own, which declares up to 6.5A and 65W.

[image: charger]

Is it safe to use such a charger on a phone that was not designed to work with it? If not, what are the risks?

Comment: Questions on the use of electronics are off-topic on this site (it's about making electronic circuits, not using them), but to give you a very short and concise answer: It's safe.

Comment: Sorry, is there a stack exchange site which would be more suitable? And second, why is it safe? Is this something controlled by software, which requests the correct amperage, or is it inherent in how chargers work?

Comment: Some batteries can supply several amps but, when they are not connected to a loading circuit, do those several amps still flow? Have you heard of Ohm's law?

Comment: @Andyaka I sure have, but it's been a while since my university days, and my physics skills are pretty rusty...

Comment: That's not a charger, it's a power supply. The actual "charger" is built in to your phone and permanently connected to the battery.

Comment: exactly.   See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the chargers meet the USB C standards correctly they will negociate the power supplied with the device.

I have a smart watch and it is USB C, I sometimes connect it directly to the 85W power supply for my laptop. Charges fine. I also sometimes connect it to the laptop hen that is on charge, also works fine.